# Shell scripting: Inserting text into a file name with a predictable pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script

Just using shell scripting, how can I insert text into the middle of a **file name**. The file has a predictable pattern, let's say 3 letters and 3 numbers and I want to insert text in the middle of those 2 **patterns**. Say ABC123 is the file name. As a result, the file name should be ABC.blah.123

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to change the file name string:

```
echo $filename | sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{3})$/\1.blah.\2/'
```

That means: Take the first 3 characters of the string if they are letters, add the string `.blah.' and add the last 3 characters of the string if they are numbers.

If you e.g. want to rename the file you could do:

```
mv "$filename" "`echo $filename | sed -r 's/(^[a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{3})$/\1.blah.\2/'`"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a recent enough `bash`, you can use parameter substrings:

```
file=ABC123
text=blah
new_file="${file:0:3}.$text.${file:3}"
```